# Browsing iis hosted WCF service give infinite loading with no data returned and blank page

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, configuration, loading

I have a website that I host about 2 WCF services on it ("service1", "service2")
two of them were working fine on the production server but suddenly
one of them "service1" when I browse its URL gives infinite loading with no response and other WCF service "service2" works fine
what I do to try to figure out the problem :

- take all the publish and make a new site on different port *5050 all services works fine but on my old port *80 "service1" not working
- I compare the security permissions between "service1" which doesn't work and "service2" which works fine => they are the same

I tried to search a lot about this problem but can't find any reason so I hope someone has a solution

Comment: What can you see from the log if you enable WCF tracing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: You must always use relative endpoint addresses for IIS-hosted service endpoints. Supplying a fully-qualified endpoint address (for example, http://localhost/MyService.svc) can lead to errors in the deployment of the service if the endpoint address does not point to the IIS-application that hosts the service exposing the endpoint. Using relative endpoint addresses for hosted services avoids these potential conflicts.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/deploying-an-internet-information-services-hosted-wcf-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN